# Ionic Firebase Promise, call a function every time a Value got changed

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

i want to create a Provider thats the only interface between my App and Firebase.
Im new to promises im sorry if im doing something horrible wrong. What i want to do is call a Function **outside my FirebaseProvider** every time a certain value changes.

 **FirebaseProvider:**

```js
onUpdateLobby(key){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      firebase.database().ref("/games").child(key).on('value',(snap)=>{
        console.log("update");
        if(snap) resolve(snap.val());
        else reject(Error("onUpdateLobby Error"));
      });
    });
  }
```

**Testpage**

```js
this.db.onUpdateLobby('test').then((snap) => {
  console.log(snap);
  // do stuff with the data
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

In my TestPage i would like to Console.Log the whole object every time something got changed, is this even possible? (I want to communicate with Firebase just via my Provider)

My Console after changing the Value 3 times looks like:

- update **(from Provider)**
- asdasdasd **(from TestPage)**
- update **(from Provider)**
- update **(from Provider)**
- update **(from Provider)**

Thanks!

Comment: Where in the TestPage are you running this code? One thing to note is that promises don't work like observables. You need to call the function to get the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment. I think the issue you're running into is that you're returning a promise rather than an `EventEmitter`. Try the following code instead.

**Firebase Provider:**

```
lobbyChanges = new EventEmitter<string>;

onUpdateLobby(key){
    firebase.database().ref("/games").child(key).on('value',(snap)=>{
        console.log("update");
        if (snap) this.lobbyChanges.emit(snap.val());
        else this.lobbyChanges.error(Error("onUpdateLobby Error"));
    });
}
```

**TestPage:**

```
this.db.lobbyChanges.subscribe(
    (snap) => {
        console.log(snap);
        // do stuff with the data
    (err) => {
        console.log(err);
});
this.db.onUpdateLobby('test')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one way of achieving what you want.

Create a public function (`listenToGamesNode()`) in your `FirebaseProvider` that takes a callback function as an argument along with the child node-key. This function registers a listener and calls the provided callback when the node is changed.

The `stopListeningToGamesNode()`-function removes the listener.

**FirebaseProvider:**

```
export class FirebaseProvider{
    private gamesRef:any;

    constructor(){
        this.gamesRef = firebase.database().ref('games');
    }

    listenToGamesNode(key, callback){
        this.gamesRef.child(key).on('value', callback);
    }

    stopListeningToGamesNode(key){
        try{
            this.gamesRef.child(key).off('value');
        }
        catch(e){
            // Handle error
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your TestPage-component, inject the `FirebaseProvider`. Use the lifecycle events `ionViewWillEnter` to start listening and `ionViewWillLeave` to stop listening to the node.

**TestPage:**

```
export class TestPage{
    private key:string = 'test';

    constructor(private firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider){}

    ionViewWillEnter(){
        this.firebaseProvider.listenToGamesNode(this.key, this.callback);
    }

    ionViewWillLeave(){
        this.firebaseProvider.stopListeningToGamesNode(this.key);
    }

    private callback(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        }
        else{
            // Handle missing node
        }
    }
}
```